# Use different target vectors for CNN

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I wish to use different target vectors (not the standard one-hot encoded) for training my CNN. My image data lies in 10 different folders (10 different categories). How do I use my desired target vectors? The `flow_from_directory()` outputs a one-hot encoded array of labels. I have the label vectors stored in a dictionary. Also, the names of the folders are the labels, if that helps.

Comment: Could you provide some code of what you have tried?

Comment: You can easily wrap the `ImageDataGenerator` inside another function and manipulate the target vector generated. Let me know if you don't know how to do that. Note that this approach only works if your customized target vectors can be inferred from the category of the image or content of the image.

Comment: @today I am unable to write that custom function. Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: @xerxes01 Did you read my updated comment? Let me explain more: this approach works if all the images in category 1 have a target vector of say `[2, 9.8, 19, 78]`, or by analyzing the content of image you can generate its target vector. Is it the case?

Comment: @today yep that's exactly the case, all images in a certain class/folder have the same target vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as you may know the [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class) in Keras is a python generator (if you are not familiar with python generators you can read more about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python)). Since you want to use customized target vectors (and not the ones generated from [`flow_from_directory()`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory)) you can manipulate the behavior of image generator by wrapping it inside another function. Here is how:

First we need to store our custom targets as a numpy array:

```py
# a numpy array containing the custom targets for each class
# custom_target[0] is target vector of class #1 images
# custom_target[1] is target vector of class #2 images
# etc.
custom_targets = your_custom_targets
```

Secondly, we create an image generator as usual and use the `flow_from_directory` to read images from disk. You need to set `class_mode` argument to `'sparse'` to obtain the class index of each image. Further, you can set `classes` argument to a list containing the name of classes (i.e. directories). If you don't set this argument the order of the classes, which will map to the label indices, will be alphanumeric (i.e. `0` for class with the highest in alphabetical order, and so on):

```py
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='sparse') # NOTE: set class_mode to sparse to generate integer indices
```

(**Note:** If you don't set `classes` argument, make sure that `custom_target[i]` corresponds to the `i`-th class in alphabetical order.)

Now we can wrap our generator inside another function and generate batches of images and their corresponding numeric labels which we use to generate our own labels:

```py
def custom_generator(generator):
    for data, labels in generator:
        # get the custom labels corresponding to each class
        custom_labels = custom_targets[labels]
        yield data, custom_labels
```

And that's it! Now we have a custom generator that we can pass it to `fit_generator` (or `predict_generator` or `evaluate_generator` for inference time) like any other generator:

```py
model.fit_generator(custom_generator(train_generator), # the rest of args)
```