# How to format X and Y data from ImageDataGenerator in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

Right now, I'm able to train and test a neural network on my image data. I'd like to be able to extract the image data and the corresponding label from the DirectoryIterator train_generator so I can perhaps shuffle this data and perform cross validation. Is there a way to extract (and possibly format if need be) this data?

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

img_width, img_height = 150, 150
train_data_dir = '/train'
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) #rescales [0,1]
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir, target_size=(img_width, img_height), shuffle=True, batch_size=32, class_mode='binary')
#I want to do something like (X, Y) = train_generator.getData()
```

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50930515/2099607) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50918151/2099607) to find out. In summary an `ImageDataGenerator` is like any other generator in python and you can iterate on them.

Comment: Actually use [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50930514/2099607) instead of mine. I think It is more efficient. The [initial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50930514/1) was wrong, as I have mentioned in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928329/getting-x-test-y-test-from-generator-in-keras/50930515#comment88860970_50930514), but he/she edited it and resolved the issue, which I was not aware of until now!

Answer (score 0):

```
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
   train_data_dir, 
   target_size=(img_width, img_height), 
   shuffle=True, 
   batch_size=SIZE_OF_DATASET,  ## change to size of entire dataset
   class_mode='binary')

for X, Y in train_generator:
   break
```